Is it possible to change the ERRORLOG files encoding in SQL Server 2019?
We have a security vendor in our company that needs to access the ERRORLOG files in some SQL Server 2019 instances. They say the encoding on our files is unusual [UTF-16 LE BOM] as the standard is [UTF-16 LE].
Is there a way to change that?

The encoding won't be "UTF-16 LE BOM". The BOM part is the Byte Order Mark and it is a little piece of the file that indicates whether the file is, for example, UFT-16 LE or UTF-16 BE. So the two encodings mentioned in your question are really the same thing. Can you double-check? Maybe you made a typo?

Not exactly sure what the vendor means by unusual or that [UTF-16 LE] is the standard. The byte order mark is optional but its presence is not unusual.
